# How to query variants on product relatedTo

Tags: ecommerce, commerce4

on my new project I decided to show in the page grid variants rather than products, but I am experiencing difficulties, since I am supposed to filter the record set based on a category relation of the product (which holds the variants) rather then on the variants themselves.

If I had to show products in the grid, this would be sufficient:

`{% paginate craft.products.relatedTo(currentCategory).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageProducts %}`

But since I want to output the variants my starting point is:

`{% paginate craft.variants.relatedTo(...?...).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageProducts %}`.

A variant holds a relation named `product` which I do not know how to use in the query builder.

I tried to play a bit with `where`, `having` and so on but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set relatedProducts = craft.products().relatedTo(currentCategory) %}
```

or if you want specific field

```
{% set relatedProducts = craft.products().relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentCategory,
    field: 'productCategoryFieldInTheProduct'
}) %}
```

and after

```
{% set variants = craft.variants.hasProduct(relatedProducts) %}
```

Where:
**currentCategory** - category query, category element or ID

Comment: Thanks @RomanAvr I'm gonna try this next week. I will keep you posted.

Comment: You are welcome.

Just tested on craft & commerce 3.x, worked for me

Comment: Just tested on commerce 4 and it works. Sorry for the delay.